# Chartjs unselected lines on render

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have a line chart with chartjs, this has 5 lines. I'd like to render the chart so only 1 line is selected and then the user can add them back in if they want to.

Normally on a chartjs chart you can click a label and the corresponding data line with remove. This is basically what I'm trying to do but on load.

I can't find anything in the documentation to support such a thing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No. Sadly not..

Comment: i'll update you if  i have a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following to the data object you want to hide on load:

```
hidden: true,
```